# How to add a button between two tableview cells

Tags: ios, swift

I am using UITableView to show the payment break up. I want to show a button between the two tableview cells.

[image: Please refer image to understand the problem in better way]
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can add it in the lower cel, while adding it set the y position as a negative value (for example -25 is the button is 50 in height), just make sure that it doesn't "clip to bounds".

Comment: @FlavioSilverio,your answer is not working.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using autolayout, it will be simpler. you can nearly get like this

[image]

Here is the Hierarchy,

```
 -> tableview
  -> contentView
    ->uiview(containerview - showing in light blue color)
    -> uiview (rounder view - dark blue)
```

rounded view is pinned with bottom and has height, width and harizontaly -Centered. container view has top,left,bottom(25), right. 
and change the conentview color accordingly. it will give you the desired result.

Comment: I want rounded view between two UITableView Cells.

Comment: I tried but can't able to get it. this is like nearly workaround.you can't inject a cell inside another one.